# is there any way to not show the yellow text when hover at image?

Tags: jquery, image, hover

As can see at jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/QPW27/123/, Whenever I hover at the image for a longer time, it will show a yellow text, with br in between, as shown in https://i.stack.imgur.com/SouyW.png.

Is there a way to not show the yellow text?
Or 
Is it possible to show yellow text with 'Pan' at first line and 'Mee' at second line?

```
var t;
$('div.img img').hover(function(){  
  var textTopPosition = $(this).position().top+17;  
  var textLeftPosition = $(this).position().left+6; 
  t = $('<div/>')
      .css({top:textTopPosition})
      .css({left:textLeftPosition})
      .text($(this).attr('title'))
  .appendTo($(this).parent());  
  $(this).fadeTo('fast',0.3);
});  

$('div.img').mouseleave(function(){
     $(this).find("img").fadeTo('fast',1);
     $(this).find("div").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using title use another attribute like a `data-title`

```
<img class="onclick" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3d561d41394ff0d5d0715b2695c3dcf0?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" data-title="Pan<br>Mee" alt="PanMee (Chinese : 板面)" onclick="bigImage(1)" style=" width:205px;height:160px; " />
```

then

```
 t = $('<div/>', {
     html: $(this).data('title'),
     css: {
         top: textTopPosition,
         left: textLeftPosition
     }
 }).appendTo($(this).parent());
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2cjax583/)